# Handling Different Child Object Names Recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I'm working with a nested JSON feed with D3.js

My code works fine when the child object is named `children`, but I want to be able display nodes for a few of other objects too, not just ones named `children`.

For example, if within the `children` object, I have another object named `options`.  I want to display nodes for that object as well.

```
{
    "item": [{
        "children": [{
            "name": "banana",
            "definition": "this is a fruit",
            "group": "n",
            "options": [
                {
                        "color": "red",
                        "shape": "square"
                }
            ],
            "countries": [
                {
                        "color": "america",
                        "shape": "africa"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "definition": "this is a fruit",
            "group": "n",
            "options": [
                {
                        "color": "red",
                        "shape": "square"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is a recursive function I have within my flatten function:

```
// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) {
            node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) { 
                return p + recurse(v);
            }, 0);
        }
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
        return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how one would go about this please?

Comment: What is your expected result? It depends on how you want it. But this would be simple if you use `for` loop to iterate through the object. For example `for(child in parent){ console.log(parent[child])}` would print out every `child` nodes of a `parent` object. And then you can just apply recursion with it.

Comment: I would like to output every item in a child object as a node. So if you had a 'children' object and a 'countries' object then I want to display both as nodes.

Comment: are you only looking for leafs, or all nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really doesn't have anything to do with jQuery or D3; it's just plain JavaScript and JSON.

If you just want your code to work with any other array in your JSON object, then it's simply a matter of replacing your if statement where you check for `d["children"]` to go through all the attributes of the JSON object and recurse on anything that is an array instead. Something like this:

```
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        for (var x in node) {
            if (Array.isArray(node[x])) {
                node.size = node[x].reduce(function(p, v) { 
                    return p + recurse(v);
                }, 0);
            }
        }

        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
        return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
```